# Creative ideas for truck display

Tags: pi-2, hardware, touchscreen

I have an older F250 with an overhead console that the 28 pin lcd has went out on. The lcd displays compass, miles till empty, ect. It has a 28 pin display from Futaba.

Any creative ideas on putting a newer lcd or maybe even a raspberry pi, or something creative as the display.
I have even considered software defined radio for my ham radio in the truck.

Not sure what components could run via the connector but I will post all the info I have. It does pull off a 12v battery in the truck.

I am not the savvy with components. I am willing to learn or perhaps even willing to pay someone who is creatively interested in the fun little project.

Lcd - FUTABA v99612 2-BT-199GN  103
Made in Taiwan

Board sticker - PT1E6BH
Board v99587 Rev

Soldered power connector
E6DB-14A624-EA

Ford Part Number
Ford 3C3Z-10D898-AA